# Version Name of an APK file

Tags: android

Can i get the versionName of an APK file which is just downloaded using the intent.
My code is as  follows:-

```
//downloading an APK from link  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse("http://mysite/myapp.apk"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Now i want  the versionName of the APK file.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks
Priya

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you install the apk file, you can try this:

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(pkg, cls);
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(comp.getPackageName(), 0);
versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

where pkg is the name of the package, and cls is the name of the class inside of pkg.